odoo17 extend method (_inherit = 'res.config.settings')and add field value not in system parameter
after run my code value field un visibel in form ,not in  system parameter  i need this message not showing  in my form  (No setting found)
(Try searching for another keyword
i need this message not showing  in my form [No setting found
Try searching for another keyword ] and after press save button value field saved
